# Unqiue usernames in firebase with no work arounds

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've looked at other answers but I'm still confused. Basically I have a firebase auth system and am trying to enforce unique usernames.

So far, I have 2 collections, a `users` collection and a `username` collection. Inside the users collection the documents contain user info. Inside the usernames collection each document id is the username and inside the documents are the userId.

To prevent duplicate usernames on user signup I was thinking to make a query to usernames collection and check if the username exists, from there either display an error to the user or continue with sign up.

code:

```
// Check if user exists

const usernamesRef = collection(db, 'usernames');
const usernameExists = query(usernamesRef, where('usernames', '==', username));

if(usernameExists) {
  // handle error
} else {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  //
}
```

My question is that is there any way to circumvent this, or is there a better way to do this. I've never done something like this before so I'm looking for input / suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see if you need this cloud function

https://bigcodenerd.org/enforce-cloud-firestore-unique-field-values/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).